# Column header name suggestions

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, tables, header, column-headers

I have a column in a table with each cell being a toggle switch (on/off),what would be an appropriate header for the column? Right now I have just called it as **state**

Comment: State of what? The header should indicate what the toggle will do.

Comment: Each row represents a policy and that particular cell switch is being used to enforce/unenforce a policy.

Comment: So ... "enforce policy".

Comment: I would label it Enforce/Unenforce .

Comment: @Mark then you force people to think about what the state represents.

Answer (score 3):

*I guess that comment is an answer*

Don't make the user guess with vague,  systems-centric labels like "state". If the switch represents turning policy enforcement on or off:

> ### Enforce policy